# How to generate a signed URL for "putObject" so that users can upload to a specific folder in AWS S3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to create a pre-signed URL to allow users to upload documents to a specific folder.

The code:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const params = {
        Bucket: 'BUCKET_NAME',
        Key: 'folderName',
        Expires: 600
    };
    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
        } else {
            resolve(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I uploaded a file using the signed URL returned from above method. I was able to upload.

Then I search for `folderName` through `headObject` method it gives me data as

`{
    "message": {
        "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
        "LastModified": "2018-02-28T11:01:33.000Z",
        "ContentLength": 55617,
        "ETag": "some e-tag string",
        "CacheControl": "no-cache",
        "ContentType": "binary/octet-stream",
        "Metadata": {}
    }
}`

and when i am trying to search for `folderName/fileName` it says `Not Found`.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here or how to generate a signed URL to upload to a specific folder. I've also searched but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You can only generate pre-signed urls for objects not folders - s3 operates on objects, folders are just conceptual to simplify the interface

Comment: @RikTurnbull Can you please suggest, what can I do if I want my users to upload files to a specific folder only OR how can i separate each user's files?

Comment: I'm not aware of a simple solution. You could use IAM roles/users and an S3 bucket policy but this doesn't really scale.